# Want to add spaces in a multi-line text in YAML

Tags: ansible, yaml

Currently I have:

```
    - name: add function definition to file
      lineinfile:
        path: /Users/alexander/Documents/test_ac.txt
        # regexp: 'before_action :check_password_expiration'
        insertbefore: 'def redirect_back_or_default*'
        line: >
          def force_authenticated_user!(*args)
            if (!current_user) and (["/explore", "/help"].include?(request.path))
              redirect_to new_user_session_path and return
            end
          end
```

Which adds into the file as

```
def force_authenticated_user!(*args)
  if (!current_user) and (["/explore", "/help"].include?(request.path))
    redirect_to new_user_session_path and return
  end
end

  def redirect_back_or_default(default: root_path, options: {})
    redirect_back(fallback_location: default, **options)
  end

  def not_found
    render_404
  end
```

I'd like to format it so that the the function definition is properly spaced, would anyone know how?

Answer (score 3):

From http://yaml-multiline.info/:

> Indentation Indicator: Ordinarily, the number of spaces you're using to indent a block will be automatically guessed from its first line. You may need a [block indentation indicator](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2793979) if the first line of the block starts with extra spaces. In this case, simply put the number of spaces used for indentation (between 1 and 9) at the end of the header.

So you should be able to do:

```
- name: add function definition to file
  lineinfile:
    path: /Users/alexander/Documents/test_ac.txt
    # regexp: 'before_action :check_password_expiration'
    insertbefore: 'def redirect_back_or_default*'
    line: >2
        def force_authenticated_user!(*args)
          if (!current_user) and (["/explore", "/help"].include?(request.path))
            redirect_to new_user_session_path and return
          end
        end
```

i.e. add the indicator and indent the code by x + 2 spaces.